# How to split a string from the word using php

Tags: php

I want to get the text in between of font tag with remove all tags using php.

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
  <P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C"
    LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">welcome</FONT>
  </P>
</TEXTFORMAT>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
  <P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C"
    LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"></FONT>
  </P>
</TEXTFORMAT>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
  <P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C"
    LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"></FONT>
  </P>
</TEXTFORMAT>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
  <P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C"
    LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"></FONT>
  </P>
</TEXTFORMAT>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
  <P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C"
    LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Test of Test asdasd</FONT>
  </P>
</TEXTFORMAT>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
  <P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C"
    LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">asdsadsadsadsad</FONT>
  </P>
</TEXTFORMAT>
```

Comment: In your case [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) might just do the trick.

Comment: Dont think about regexp, we all know what will happen then. ;)

Comment: @ToBe I agree, upvoted your comment. Check my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your xml is allways valid xml (html certainly is not), you could import it into a DomDocument and get all Font-Nodes via Xpath queries.

This way, you would also still have the full node in question with all its attributes, parents and children.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument($input);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = '//FONT';

$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry)
    echo $entry->nodeValue;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/de/domxpath.query.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$your_tagged_text = '<SOME TAGS VALUE="FOO"><FONT FACE="FONT">Your Text</FONT></SOME TAGS>';
$your_plain_text = strip_tags($your_tagged_text);

print $your_plain_text;
```

Returns : "Your Text"

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Let's do Regular Expressions on HTML. I expect at least 10 down votes :D

```
<?php
    $string = '<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">welcome</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT><TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT><TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT><TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"></FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT><TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Test of Test asdasd </FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT><TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">asdsadsadsadsad</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>';

    $result = preg_match_all("/<font.*?>(.*?)<\/font>/si", $string, $matches);

    if (count($matches) > 0) {
        unset($matches[0][0]);

        foreach($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
            echo $key.' >>> '.$value;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Trying to get that badge huh?

Comment: I thought "PEER PRESSURE" was 10 downvotes and a delete. It's actually 3... :(

Comment: I'm not even aware of the badges :P. Anyways; if the OP downsizes the RegEx search to the HTML part he only shows, it shouldn't cause much issues. When using RegEx in HTML (even on `innerHTML`), on should always validate the structure upfront. Nonetheless; nothing wrong with different approaches. I use RegEx often enough on narrowed HTML chunks, and never have any issues with it. Not even with weird encoding.

Comment: True, and besided working in some cases, that famous html regexp parsing answer (still no.1 on this site) was probably the best (if not helpfull) answer i ever found ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using this "XML" :

```
$string = '<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
  <P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C"
    LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">welcome</FONT>
  </P>
</TEXTFORMAT>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
  <P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C"
    LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"></FONT>
  </P>
</TEXTFORMAT>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
  <P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C"
    LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"></FONT>
  </P>
</TEXTFORMAT>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
  <P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C"
    LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0"></FONT>
  </P>
</TEXTFORMAT>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
  <P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C"
    LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Test of Test asdasd</FONT>
  </P>
</TEXTFORMAT>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
  <P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C"
    LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">asdsadsadsadsad</FONT>
  </P>
</TEXTFORMAT>';
```

### You can remove all tags using [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
echo strip_tags($string);
```

### Or you can parse this with [simpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) :

```
$string = '<data>'.$string.'</data>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml as $t){
    echo $t->P->FONT.'<br/>';
}
```